# Limit the size of for loop result

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am using a for loop to parse a GPX file in android and put the resulting lat and long in a string suitable for google static maps. The static maps api allows urls up to ~2000 characters.

What I want to do is loop over the entries in the gpx file such that I get the maximum amount of detail without producing too many characters. For example if a lat and long is 10 characters  then I always want to produce as close to 200 markers as possible.

I am starting with this working code

```
List<Location> gpxList = decodeGPX(gpxFile);
for(int i = 0; i < gpxList.size(); i++){
    info += ((Location)gpxList.get(i)).getLatitude()
            + ","
            + ((Location)gpxList.get(i)).getLongitude() + "|";
}
```

The obvious way to do this would be to take the length of the list and divide by the maximum number of markers allowed (200 in this example), ensure this is a whole number and then increment this many items when the loop iterates. But how do I ensure that I dont get an out of  bounds error at the end of the list?

EDIT

To be clear I want to reduce the frequency of the data points rather than reduce the number of points if that makes sense. Imagine I have a gpx file with 2000 marks that gives a round-trip. I want to produce a list of 200 points that still gives the full trip (with a loss in precision) rather than just listing the first 200 points which only gives the beginning of the trip

Answer (score 1):

Before adding new characters to the `info` String (I'm assuming it's a String), check the number of characters to be added, and verify there enough room in the `info` String. If not, end the loop.

```
List<Location> gpxList = decodeGPX(gpxFile);
boolean hasRoom = true;
for(int i = 0; i < gpxList.size() && hasRoom; i++) {
    String next = ((Location)gpxList.get(i)).getLatitude()
            + ","
            + ((Location)gpxList.get(i)).getLongitude() + "|";
    if (info.length()+next.length()<=2000)
        info += next;
    else
        hasRoom = false;
}
```

Comment: Consider using one StringBuilder (created before loop) rather than creating String inside loop and doing String contatenation. Solution with Strings creates a lot of objects- that is a lot of work for garbage collector.

Comment: @BartoszBilicki I totally agree. I simply based my answer on the OP's code. I usually change code with `+` operator on Strings to use StringBuilder instead.

Comment: Thanks but not quite what I am looking for. My fault, I will add an edit to try and clear this up